# How to run Filemaker using fmp:// cmd?

Tags: windows, autoit, filemaker, shellexecute

I have a Filemaker v14 database that executes a compiled AutoIt script. It does things that Filemaker can't, then returns a `fmp://` url (initiating a Filemaker script by parameters from the url). But I can't figure out how to send that url from an AutoIt script.

I used [WINHTTP](http://brugbart.com/http-get-request-autoit) but it doesn't like the `fmp://` protocol, and [`Run()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm) in various configurations but can't find one that works.

The url works fine through a browser address bar but I need to script sending the request. The database and AutoIt script are on the same PC. Does anybody know how this might be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

[The solution](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm) is simple:

```
ShellExecute("fmp://My/Really/Long/URL")
```